# How to detect when pattern matcher find finds invalid input?

Tags: java, exception, matcher

Matcher.find() looks for any expression specified in the regular expression given to the pattern, but how can we detect when an expression not specified in the regex?

```
    String input = "& 9 then %"
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(|then|def|[0-9]+");
    Matcher match = pattern.Matcher(input);

       while (match.find()) {
       ...
       ...
    }
```

The input has the symbol & and % which will not be detected, but I want to throw an exception when these symbols are not, so how can I detect that?

Comment: 1) You are missing some quotes there. 2) Why do you have `then` listed twice? 3) Add `|\\S+` at the end to capture any non-valid token too, then check for it in the `while` loop.

Comment: Post actual code. The one you posted is missing pair of "

Comment: I fixed code but if I add \\S+, I do a case where if(match.group().matches("\\S+")) then System.out.println("invalid"); but this just consumes every single token

Comment: So I am presuming i add the above code at the very end of all the cases so it picks up anything that doesnt matches?